# How should I resolve Springframework.Dispatcherservlet error?

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, servlets

I was trying to run springmvc code in tomcat server that threw an error regarding servlet, like this:-

> SEVERE: Servlet [SpringMVC] in web application [/SpringMVC] threw
>   load() exception java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispactherServlet     at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1308)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1136)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:544)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:525)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:150)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1044)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:983)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4978)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5290)

Then I tried to resolve this using deployment assembly, but in the last step I could not add folder because the finish button was disabled.I am not sure if I am doing it right or is there any other resolution?

The steps I tried:-

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: As per what I understand, you already have `Maven Dependencies` added already. That's why you are not able to add. Maybe you can remove once and try to add again.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using the eclipse 's built-in Maven plugin ([M2Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/m2e/)) to manage the dependencies , you don't need to configure them at `Deployment Assembly` manually as M2Eclipse will manage them for you.

So , configure your `pom.xml` and make sure to include the following spring mvc required dependencies. (Suppose you are using Spring5)

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>


<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: thanks, I included according to my version but error still exists... :(

Comment: java version is 1.8 and tomcat is 8.5, does this make any issue? because I see a note in tomcat window it works upto java 7 for web...